# UICollectionView, Cell selection not working, cell scrolls fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

So I have a uicollectionview, which resides inside a view controller, in this VC I have some buttons and other controls, and I load data into the CollectionView, I cannot detect the click on the collectionview, but it responds to scrolls fine.
All I can think of is that sometimes I enable userinteraction on all subviews in my view ( including the collectionview) , and this works, in the sense that no controls work, and then based on another condition I enable activity.

this is an example of the code

```
if (_isMenuVisible) {
  for (UIView *subview in [self.actualView subviews]) {
     if([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]] || [subview isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]] ||   [subview isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        subview.userInteractionEnabled = _isMenuVisible;
     }
     else {
        subview.userInteractionEnabled = !_isMenuVisible;
     }
  }
}
else {
  for (UIView *subview in [self.actualView subviews]) {
        subview.userInteractionEnabled = !_isMenuVisible;
  }
}
```

Could this affect the behavior?

Comment: set the break point in the above code and check if user interaction is disabled..

Comment: Are you setting the delegate property of UICollectionView? In order to respond to collection view cell selection, you should implement `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` on the delegate of the collection view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your ViewController adopts the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol. Then, as mentioned above, simply override the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` to decide what you want to do when a certain cell is clicked.

Use the indexPath to determine the row or section of the cell by accessing its row or section property.

Comment: Please elaborate what is this: UICollectionViewCellDelegate?

Comment: There is no such in the iOS SDK. Please don't be a jerk @AdamWaite

Comment: Huh @Marchy? Didn't say anything?